# Change the background color of every other group in Excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'p': ['short', np.nan, 'short', np.nan, np.nan, 'long', 'long', np.nan, np.nan],
        's': [13, 13, 14, 15, 100, 1, 1000, 12, 1111]
    }
)
```

I want to change the background color of every other group (even groups) to a different color in Excel.

This is what I want in Excel:

[image]

The groups are defined based on `p`. That is a value in `p` and all of the `NaN` values below it, is one group. It is clear in the image above.

This is what I have tried but did not work:

```
from matplotlib import colors
def colr(x):
    y = x.assign(k=x['p'].ne(x['p'].shift()).cumsum())

    d = dict(enumerate(colors.cnames))
    y[:] = np.broadcast_to(y['k'].map(d).radd('background-color:').to_numpy()[:,None]
                          ,y.shape)
    return y.drop("k",1)

df = df.style.apply(colr,axis=None)
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create even groups by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) by testing not missing values and forward filling values with modulo `2` and integer division `2`, last use your solution for mapping colors with set no color for odd groups by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'p': ['short', np.nan, 'short', np.nan, np.nan,'short',np.nan, 
              'short', np.nan, 'long', 'long', np.nan, np.nan, 
              'long','long','long','long'],
        's': [13, 13, 14, 15, 100, 8,9,6,4,8, 1000, 12, 1111,7,8,79,87]
    }
)


from matplotlib import colors
def colr(x):
    p = x['p'].notna().groupby(x['p']).cumsum().ffill() 
    m = p % 2 == 1
    s = p // 2

    d = dict(enumerate(colors.cnames))
    out = np.broadcast_to(s.map(d).radd('background-color:').to_numpy()[:,None]
                          ,x.shape)

    return np.where(m.to_numpy()[:, None], '', out)

df = df.style.apply(colr,axis=None)
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

[image: pic]